# AWS CLoudformation Template for 20 Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am currently working on a project that contains around 20 Lambda functions in a single cloudformation template. Now that i have got a requirement to make change in one lambda due to that am deploying entire stack with no choice.I do feel that some time that am messing up something because the entire stack is going through deployment process.

Is there a better way to decouple entire stack ?

The only way i am thinking of is to group the lambdas in to multiple stacks depends on functional dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using serverless framework then it possible single function deployment.But (wants to deploy) function available in the stack.

command

```
sls deploy -f <function_name>
```

if function not available in stack means not previously deployed then you have to deploy whole stack

```
sls deploy
```